# "ConstraintLayout could not be instantiated" while rendering

Tags: java, android, maven, android-layout, android-maven-plugin

I am using Maven with `android-maven-plugin` as a build tool for Android development. I am trying to use `ConstraintLayout` in my project.
In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
<repository>
                <id>google</id>
                <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
            <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to render a view that contains the `ConstraintLayout` class I face the following message with an exception. (Standard layouts are rendered without any errors)

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/constraint/R$styleable
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:440)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:946)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: got the same issue, have u solve it? BTW, I tried some different version and not work :(

Comment: I got the same issue, first the constraintlayout was import in the Library module's `build.gradle` file. when i move it into the app's `build.gradle` file, it work fine, hope can help u!